# How to manage offsets in KafkaItemReader used in spring batch job in case of any exception occurs in mid of reading messages

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-batch, kafka-consumer-api

I am working on a Kafka based spring boot application for the first time. My requirement was to create an output file with all the records using spring batch. I created a spring batch job where integrated with a customized class which extends KafkaItemReader. I don't want to commit the offsets for now as i might need to go back read some records from already consumed offsets. My consumer config has these properties;

enable.auto.commit: false
auto-offset-reset: latest
group.id:

There are two scenarios->
1. A happy path, where i can read all the messages from kafka topic and transform them and then write them to an output file using above configuration.
2. I am getting an exception while reading thru' the messages, and i am not sure how to manage the offsets in such cases. Even if i go back to rest the offset, how to make sure it is the correct offset for messages. I dont persist the payload of message record anywhere except it goes to the spring batch output file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a persistent Job Repository for that and configure the `KafkaItemReader` to [save its state](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/kafka/KafkaItemReader.html#setSaveState-boolean-). The state consists in the offset of each partition assigned to the reader and will be saved at chunk boundaries (aka at each transaction).

In a restart scenario, the reader will be initialized with the last offset for each partition from the execution context and resume where it left off.

Comment: Can you share some example for this?

Comment: Sure, take a look at this test case: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/a140a9f5a14b250af94ea4624501068b647b4bbb/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/kafka/KafkaItemReaderTests.java#L240

Comment: Is it going to work if i never commits the message to kafka topic because i don't want to commit he messages at least for a few months.

Comment: It should since it will be saved in the execution context of Spring Batch meta data table.

Comment: I explored this one but i think since we don't have any track of offsets either in Kafka or outside Kafka, its going to be complex in case application fails or some unexpected circumstances. So i was thinking of storing the offsets out of kafka .

Comment: `we don't have any track of offsets either in Kafka or outside Kafka`: If you use a persistent job repository as mentioned in the answer, you do have track of offsets in the meta-data table of Spring Batch (outside of kafka).