# How to commit the offsets when using KafkaItemReader in spring batch job, once all the messages are processed and written to the .dat file?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-batch, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have developed a Spring Batch Job which read from Kafka topic using KafkaItemReader class. I want to commit the offset only when the messages read in defined chunk are Processed and written successfully to an Output .dat file.

```
@Bean
public Job kafkaEventReformatjob(
        @Qualifier("MaintStep") Step MainStep,
        @Qualifier("moveFileToFolder") Step moveFileToFolder,
        @Qualifier("compressFile") Step compressFile,
        JobExecutionListener listener)
{
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("kafkaEventReformatJob")
            .listener(listener)
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(MainStep)
            .next(moveFileToFolder)
            .next(compressFile)
            .end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
Step MainStep(
        ItemProcessor<IncomingRecord, List<Record>> flatFileItemProcessor,
        ItemWriter<List<Record>> flatFileWriter)
{
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("mainStep")
            .<InputRecord, List<Record>> chunk(5000)
            .reader(kafkaItemReader())
            .processor(flatFileItemProcessor)
            .writer(writer())
            .listener(basicStepListener)
            .build();
}
//Reader reads all the messages from akfka topic and sending back in form of IncomingRecord.
 @Bean
KafkaItemReader<String, IncomingRecord> kafkaItemReader() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.putAll(this.properties.buildConsumerProperties());
    List<Integer> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
    partitions.add(0);
    partitions.add(1);
    return new KafkaItemReaderBuilder<String, IncomingRecord>()
            .partitions(partitions)
            .consumerProperties(props)
            .name("records")
            .saveState(true)
            .topic(topic)
            .pollTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(40L))
            .build();
}

  @Bean
public ItemWriter<List<Record>> writer() {
    ListUnpackingItemWriter<Record> listUnpackingItemWriter = new ListUnpackingItemWriter<>();
    listUnpackingItemWriter.setDelegate(flatWriter());
    return listUnpackingItemWriter;
}

public ItemWriter<Record> flatWriter() {
    FlatFileItemWriter<Record> fileWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    String tempFileName = "abc";
    LOGGER.info("Output File name " + tempFileName + " is in working directory ");
    String workingDir = service.getWorkingDir().toAbsolutePath().toString();
    Path outputFile = Paths.get(workingDir, tempFileName);
    fileWriter.setName("fileWriter");
    fileWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(outputFile.toString()));
    fileWriter.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator());
    fileWriter.setForceSync(true);
    fileWriter.setFooterCallback(customFooterCallback());
    fileWriter.close();
    LOGGER.info("Successfully created the file writer");
    return fileWriter;

}

@StepScope
@Bean
public TransformProcessor processor() {
    return new TransformProcessor();
}
```

==============================================================================

## Writer Class

```
 @BeforeStep
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
}

@AfterStep
public void afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.stepExecution.setWriteCount(count);
}

@Override
public void write(final List<? extends List<Record>> lists) throws Exception {

    List<Record> consolidatedList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<Record> list : lists) {
        if (!list.isEmpty() && null != list)
            consolidatedList.addAll(list);
    }

    delegate.write(consolidatedList);
    count += consolidatedList.size(); // to count Trailer record count
}
```

===============================================================

## Item Processor

@Override
    public List process(IncomingRecord record) {

```
    List<Record> recordList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (null != record.getEventName() and a few other conditions inside this section) {
        // setting values of Record Class by extracting from the IncomingRecord.
        recordList.add(the valid records which matching the condition);
        }else{
        return null;
        }
```

Comment: Is the file system where you write your output .dat file transactional?

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit? How transactional?

Comment: oh sorry for not being clear. There are transactional file systems and non transaction ones. A transactional file system allows you to do atomic write operations. For example, if you flush a buffer to a file and there is no more space on disk, then you can rollback the entire buffer. With a non transactional file system, you would have a partially flushed buffer and the file could be corrupted. Do you see? More details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system#Transactional_file_systems. So, is your file system transactional?

Comment: Please don't add code in comments, it is not readable. You can always edit the question and add code. I was talking about the file system and not the job repository. Anyway, I will add an answer to try to help.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronizing a read operation and a write operation between two transactional resources (a queue and a database for instance)
is possible by using a JTA transaction manager that coordinates both transaction managers (2PC protocol).

However, this approach is not possible if one of the resources is not transactional (like the majority of file systems). So unless you use
a transactional file system and a JTA transaction manager that coordinates a kafka transaction manager and a file system transaction manager..
you need another approach, like the [Compensating Transaction pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/compensating-transaction). In your case, the "undo" operation (compensating action) would be rewinding the offset where it was before the failed chunk.

Comment: Could you please share an example ?

Comment: If you share a repo with a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I can try to help.

Comment: Thanks. However, the code only is not enough. I need to reproduce your problem to see how to help (see "Reproducible" section in the link I shared). `I want to commit the offset only when the messages read in defined chunk are Processed and written successfully to an Output .dat file.` : do you have an example where the chunk fails to be written to the file?

Comment: So, I am creating a temporary file of incoming records in one directory. When job completes successfully the temporary file is compressed and moved to the another directory which has the final files. So in case my job fails the file will remain in the directory with temp files.

Comment: If you use a persistent job repository and restart your job after a failure, the kafka reader should read from the last offset stored in the execution context, as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60316495/5019386.

Comment: The update method of KafkaItemReader has commitSync() which commits the offsets once chink of messages are read, processed and written but how to validate if it has committed the messages. Because when i ran the job next time, it starts from the initial offsets only for both the partitions.

Comment: Please note the offset is stored in two places: on kafka side (with `kafkaConsumer.commitSync`) and on Spring Batch side (with `executionContext.put(partition, offset)`). If you want to validate if the commitSync has committed or not and make sure the info is in sync between Spring Batch and kafka, you need to use a kafka transaction manager as explained in the answer.

Comment: I am able to commit the messages and next time i ran the job its giving no records and show the latest offsets only.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't follow anymore. You did not provide a minimal **reproducible** example I can run and debug to understand your exact issue, but I did my best to try to help with what you shared. If you think there is something missing in Spring Batch, please open an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help you provided. I didn't have to do much as KafkaItemReader class provides everything to keep the sync between spring batch and kafka when committing the offsets.